# How to assign personal view to specific user?

Tags: development, client-object-model, list-view

Usually I create view using ViewCreationInformation class:

```
public static void Create(this ViewCollection viewCollection, IListView view, string desiredTitle, ContentTypeId contentTypeId)
{
    //create
    var viewCreationInfo = view.ToViewCreationInformation();
    //mark for futher process
    viewCreationInfo.Title = view.SystemTitle;
    //upload to server
    viewCollection.Add(viewCreationInfo);
    viewCollection.Context.ExecuteQuery();

    var createdView = viewCollection.GetByTitle(view.SystemTitle);
    createdView.LoadAndExecute(c=>c.ViewType, c=>c.PersonalView);

    //update
    createdView.UpdateAggregations(view);
    createdView.Title = desiredTitle;
    createdView.ContentTypeId = contentTypeId;
    createdView.ViewData = view.ViewData;

    ViewType viewType;
    if (!createdView.PersonalView && Enum.TryParse(createdView.ViewType, true, out viewType) && viewType == ViewType.Html)
    {
        createdView.MobileDefaultView = view.IsMobileDefaultView();
        createdView.MobileView = view.IsMobileView();
    }

    //save
    createdView.Update();
    viewCollection.Context.ExecuteQuery();
}

public static ViewCreationInformation ToViewCreationInformation(this IListView listView)
{
    return new ViewCreationInformation
    {
        Query = listView.Query,
        Paged = listView.IsPaged,
        RowLimit = Convert.ToUInt32(listView.RowLimit),
        SetAsDefaultView = listView.IsDefault,
        ViewFields = listView.Fields?.ToArray(),
        ViewTypeKind = listView.GetViewType(),
        PersonalView = listView.IsPersonalView()
    };
}

public static void UpdateAggregations(this View spView, IListView veeamView)
{
    //!!!The order of assigning  is VERY IMPORTANT here
    //it's just a SP

    spView.Aggregations = veeamView.Aggregations;
    spView.AggregationsStatus = veeamView.AggregationsStatus.ToString();
}
```

But I have a problem there.
I have no idea how to specify that a specific personal view belongs to a specific user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot assign the personal view to specific user directly in SharePoint.

There is a workaround.

We can get the user who logins the SharePoint site. And then redirect to different view according to the different users who login the SharePoint site.

More reference:

[How to Get the Current User's Properties Using CSOM in SharePoint 2013.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-current-users-properties-using-csom-in-share/)

Comment: And Is it possible to retrieve data about whom this view is belonged to via csom ? Or how i can find this info in WSS_Content database directly.

Answer (score 1):

for me the easiest workaround is adding a "Users View" Column

i would add to that column all the people i want to give access to that view and on the view filter i would set the filter by [Me]

then i would remove that field from the view so no one can create another view